# Update Display state when App state changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React with Hooks.
I have a `App` as parent component with `const [key, setKey] = useState("");`
and a `Display` component (imported from another `.js` file and called called as `<Display />` in my App render) that needs to update every time `key` is updated.

Disclaimer: I have a feeling there is a super "nose on the face" answer, but I've been looking in SO and React documentation for hours and can't find a straight answer to this. I'm really sorry if it's a repeat question, I swear it's not from laziness on my end, but real desperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with another name, I would said `aKey`. Here is what you can do:
You can pass `aKey` as prop in Display, like this:

```
<Display aKey={aKey}/>
```

and then in Display component definition:

```
const Display = ({aKey}) => { ... }
```

So now when `aKey` gets updated in `App` it will also change in `Display` component.